# enzyme wrappers fail jest equality despite producing identical snapshots

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, snapshot

Here's a simple React component with an optional prop with a default value:

```
class Test extends Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    role: 'default'
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div role={this.props.role}>
        { this.props.children }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In the test, I'm mounting this component twice, once omitting the optional prop and once specifying the default value for the prop:

```
import toJson from 'enzyme-to-json';
import { mount } from 'enzyme';
...
test('should render the same tree', () => {

  const a = mount(<Test />);
  const b = mount(<Test role="default" />);

  expect(toJson(a)).toMatchSnapshot();  // passes
  expect(toJson(b)).toMatchSnapshot();  // passes
  expect(toJson(a)).toEqual(toJson(b)); // fails
});
```

Unexpectedly, `expect(toJson(a)).toEqual(toJson(b));` is failing. However, Jest confirms that the resulting tree is identical, as it logs the `no visual difference` message:

```
  ● should render the same tree

    expect(received).toEqual(expected)

    Expected value to equal:
      <Test role="default"><div role="default" /></Test>
    Received:
      <Test role="default"><div role="default" /></Test>

    Difference:

    Compared values have no visual difference.

      43 |       expect(toJson(a)).toMatchSnapshot();
      44 |       expect(toJson(b)).toMatchSnapshot();
    > 45 |       expect(toJson(a)).toEqual(toJson(b));
         |                         ^
      46 |     });
      47 | 
      48 |
```

Furthermore, as expected, this produces identical snapshots for the case when the optional property is omitted as well as when it's provided with the default value:

```
exports[`should render the same tree 1`] = `
<Test
  role="default"
>
  <div
    role="default"
  />
</Test>
`;

exports[`should render the same tree 2`] = `
<Test
  role="default"
>
  <div
    role="default"
  />
</Test>
`;
```

I'm struggling to figure out why this test case is failing.

- What am I missing?
- Why is this equality check failing despite the duplicate snapshots?
- Could it be related to the `toJson` utility function from `enzyme-to-json`?
- Could it be related to `enzyme` itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The helper function in `enzyme-to-json` is called `toJson()` but that is a bit of a misnomer.  It doesn't return back JSON, it actually returns back a quite complicated object that the Jest `toMatchSnapshot()` then converts into the JSON that ends up in the snapshot file.

The simplified view of the two objects at the highest level returns `no visual difference` but if you go one level deeper into the `node` key you can start to see the differences:

`expect(toJson(a).node).toEqual(toJson(b).node);`

Comment: It seems like `_debugID` (at multiple levels in the tree) is the difference. Is this relevant to the actual DOM tree being rendered though?

Comment: @Hristo it's not relevant to the rendered DOM tree, but [`toEqual`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect#toequalvalue) doesn't know that and is just doing a deep equal on the two objects.  Since there are values within the objects that differ the assertion fails.

Comment: Oh right, good point. Maybe I could ignore those key/value pairs, though that seems more of a hack than a solution.

Comment: @Hristo one suggestion: if you are just trying to compare the shallow-generated html you could do this `expect(a.html()).toEqual(b.html());`

Comment: Yes, I tried that, and it works. I'm pretty new to using Jest for testing React components, and I'm not sure if it's good practice to use `.html()` as a equality check.

Comment: @Hristo I think you're good with the two snapshot tests.  They verify that the component is working as expected in both cases.  Anything more than that is redundant IMHO

Comment: slightly different question... the two "toMatchSnapshot()" asserts end up generating duplicate snapshots, which seems not ideal. do you know how to avoid this?

Comment: @Hristo it's okay, the snapshot file for a test file stores each snapshot as `'<test name> <index>'` so every snapshot has a unique name and Jest knows how to associate each snapshot test with each snapshot.  In this case `'should render the same tree 1'` goes with `toJson(a)` and `'should render the same tree 2'` goes with `toJson(b)` since the snapshots were taken in that order in the test `'should render the same tree'`